# AWS CodeDeploy - Must be connected to a terminal

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, bash

I have a CICD Bitbucket pipeline that runs and tries to execute a deployment script.

**appspec.yml**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux

    files:
      - source: scripts/osgi-deploy.sh
        destination: /home/jboss
        overwrite: true
    file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
    hooks:
      AfterInstall:
        - location: scripts/osgi-deploy.sh
          timeout: 180
          runas: jboss
```

**osgi-deploy.sh**

```
echo "about to deploy to osgi-app ($USER) ..."
screen -d -m -R "karaf" bash /home/jboss/scripts/build-start-osgi.sh &
```

**Output**

```
about to deploy to osgi-app (jboss) ...
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

As you can see, the `osgi-deploy.sh` file is executed and tries to start a `screen`, however because it is running from an external process (AWS CodeDeploy), it says it `Must be connected to a terminal`. If I run the `osgi-deploy.sh` from a CLI it works as expected.

I have tried to detach the screen using the `-d` parameter, but that doesn't work.

Comment: omit the screen. It seems useless in that case anyway.

Comment: The reason for the `screen` is so that I start the application server (Apache Karaf) in the screen so that users can access it via the CLI. Also there is more than on application running on this server.